# Why is updating state not causing a re-render (updating state using drag and drop)?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, state

I am making a card system that can swap cards using drag and drop. When I'm dragging the cards over each other my state is updating as it's supposed to but it's not re-rendering.

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import DnDGroup from './DndGroup';

const DragNDrop = ({data}) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(data);

  const dragItem = useRef();
  const dragNode = useRef();

  const getParams = (element) => {
    const itemNum = element.toString();
    const group = list.find(group => group.items.find(item => item === itemNum))
    const groupIndex = list.indexOf(group);
    const itemIndex = group.items.indexOf(itemNum);
    return {'groupIndex': groupIndex, 'itemIndex': itemIndex}
  }

  const handleDragstart = (e) => {
    dragNode.current = e.target;
    setTimeout(() => {
      dragNode.current.classList.add('current')
    }, 0)    
    dragItem.current = getParams(e.target.value);

    dragNode.current.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
      if(dragNode.current !== undefined) {
        dragNode.current.classList.remove('current')
      } 
    })
  }

  const handleDragEnter = e => {
    if(dragNode.current !== e.target && e.target.value !== undefined) {
      const node = getParams(e.target.value);
      const currentItem = dragItem.current;
      [data[currentItem.groupIndex].items[currentItem.itemIndex], data[node.groupIndex].items[node.itemIndex]] = [data[node.groupIndex].items[node.itemIndex], data[currentItem.groupIndex].items[currentItem.itemIndex]];
      setList(data);
      console.log(list)
    } 
  } 

    return (
    <div className='drag-n-drop'>
      {list.map(group => (
        <DnDGroup 
          key={group.title} 
          group={group} 
          handleDragstart={handleDragstart}
          handleDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
        />
      ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default DragNDrop;
```

I also tried to do this:

```
setList([...data])
```

Using this it renders according to the state changes and works great inside one group, but when I want to drag a card to the other group, the state constantly changes back and forth like crazy, it also gives tons of console.logs.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Because you're mutating the state in the prior line. Never mutate state in React.

Comment: How can I use my current state for updating?

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
[data[currentItem.groupIndex].items[currentItem.itemIndex], data[node.groupIndex].items[node.itemIndex]] = [data[node.groupIndex].items[node.itemIndex], data[currentItem.groupIndex].items[currentItem.itemIndex]];
```

you're mutating a deeply nested object inside the `data` array. Never mutate state in React; it can result in components not re-rendering when you expect them to, in addition to other unexpected (and undesirable) side-effects.

Another thing that looks like it's *probably* an unintentional bug is that you're changing the `data` (original state) instead of the stateful `list` array.

Change it to:

```
const itemA = list[node.groupIndex].items[node.itemIndex];
const itemB = list[currentItem.groupIndex].items[currentItem.itemIndex];
const newList = [...list];
newList[currentItem.groupIndex] = {
    ...newList[currentItem.groupIndex],
    items: newList[currentItem.groupIndex].map(
        (item, i) => i !== currentItem.itemIndex ? item : itemB
    )
};
newList[node.groupIndex] = {
    ...newList[node.groupIndex],
    items: newList[node.groupIndex].map(
        (item, i) => i !== node.itemIndex ? item : itemA
    )
};
setList(newList);
```

This avoids the mutation of the nested `items` subarray.

Comment: I tried using this, but it's not working. I had to do add "items" before the mapping in order to get the map-function work. But it didn't change anything on the state. Next I switched the itemA and itemB, but if I do that, I get the same problem that I already had using my own code.